# What's the best way of dealing with optional and dynamic function parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

This is my function that generates and returns an array (Please see the comments in the code below):

```
const getStylesArray = (noteBlockSettings, blockId, key, value) => {

    // ---------------------------------------------------
    // noteBlockSettings parameter will be passed to this function no matter what. 
    // So it is definetely not undefined.

    // NoteBlockSettings has bgOpacity, bgColor, primaryColor, secondaryColor, textColor keys and values.

    // key and value parameters of this function are optional, so they may be undefined or not.

    // ***** What i am trying to achieve is : *****
    // If key parameter is passed (can be bgOpacity, bgColor, primaryColor, secondaryColor, textColor)
    // use this passed parameter rather than the value in noteBlockSettings object. 
    // If key parameter is undefined, use the value in noteBlockSettings object.
    
    // ---------------------------------------------------

    let { bgColor, primaryColor, secondaryColor, bgOpacity, textColor } = noteBlockSettings

    if (key === 'bgColor') {
         bgColor = value
    }

    if (key === 'primaryColor') {
         primaryColor = value
    }

    if (key === 'secondaryColor') {
         secondaryColor = value
    }

    if (key === 'bgOpacity') {
         bgOpacity = value
    }

    if (key === 'textColor') {
         textColor = value
    }


    const stylesArray = [
         // Here i am using the variables defined above to dynamically generate the array
         // Like bgOpacity, bgColor, primaryColor, secondaryColor, textColor etc..
         {
              styleClass: '.head',
              styleValue: `background:${addAlpha(colord(bgColor).lighten(0.075).toHex(), bgOpacity)}; border-color:${addAlpha(colord(bgColor).darken(0.06).toHex(), bgOpacity)};`,
              styleTriggers: 'bgColor bgOpacity',
         },

         {
              styleClass: '.head .options .btn-icon',
              styleValue: `color:${addAlpha(colord(textColor), 0.4)};`,
              styleTriggers: 'textColor',
         },

         {
              styleClass: '.head .options .btn-icon:hover',
              styleValue: `color:${primaryColor};`,
              styleTriggers: 'primaryColor',
         },
         .
         .
         .
    ]

    // Finally returning the generated array 
    return stylesArray
}
```

This is working and it is just a primitive attempt. However I don't know how, but I feel like there should be much "smarter" way of handling this.

**So, my question is: What is the best and minimal way of achieving the same result?**

Comment: I read your title several times, trying to figure out what an optional "&& dynamic function" was, unless maybe it was meant to be an "optional &&" dynamic function? Or an optional "&& dynamic" function? Until I realised you just wanted to save time by writing "&&" instead of "and"... && belongs to computer languages, not human ones

Comment: @JeremyThille Sorry, it is definitely my bad. Thanks for pointing out and your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a "final" settings object before destructuring it. Then you don't need to check every variable:

```
// If `key` is passed and a valid key in the object, copy the object and overwrite
// the property. 
const finalSettings = key in noteBlockSettings ? 
   {...noteBlockSettings, [key]: value} :
   noteBockSettings;

const { bgColor, primaryColor, secondaryColor, bgOpacity, textColor } = finalSettings;
// ...
```

`{...noteBlockSettings, [key]: value}` basically copies `noteBlockSettings` and sets the property whose name is in `key` to `value`.

Having said that, I'm wondering why the call site simply doesn't pass the complete settings object. That would make the API clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get a copy of the `noteBlockSettings` then extract each values in it.

1. Copy the values by doing

```
let copy = {...original};
```

2. Modify any key:

```
copy[key] = value;
```

3. Extract the values like you did before

```
let {a, b, c, d, e, ...} = copy
```

```js
const mutateStyles = (noteBlockSettings, blockId, key, value) => {

    // ---------------------------------------------------
    // noteBlockSettings parameter will be passed to this function no matter what. 
    // So it is definetely not undefined.

    // NoteBlockSettings has bgOpacity, bgColor, primaryColor, secondaryColor, textColor keys and values.

    // key and value parameters of this function are optional, so they may be undefined or not.

    // ***** What i am trying to achieve is : *****
    // If key parameter is passed (can be bgOpacity, bgColor, primaryColor, secondaryColor, textColor)
    // use this passed parameter rather than the value in noteBlockSettings object. 
    // If key parameter is undefined, use the value in noteBlockSettings object.
    
    // ---------------------------------------------------

    let noteBlockSettingsCopy = {...noteBlockSettings}

    noteBlockSettingsCopy[key] = value;
    
    let { bgColor, primaryColor, secondaryColor, bgOpacity, textColor } = noteBlockSettingsCopy

    return noteBlockSettingsCopy;
}

let data = { bgColor: "#fff", primaryColor: '#0ff', secondaryColor: "#ff0", bgOpacity: "0.1", textColor: "#000" };

console.log(mutateStyles(data, 1, "bgColor", "#f0f"));
```